# Opening up a .tar file on Windows

Tags: windows, compression, tar

What Windows tool or program can I use to open a **.tar** file? I also have **.tar.gz** files that I would like to open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

> - High compression ratio in new 7z format with LZMA compression
> - Supported formats:
>
>   - Packing / unpacking: 7z, ZIP, GZIP, BZIP2 and TAR
>   - Unpacking only: ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, DEB, DMG, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MSI, NSIS, RAR, RPM, UDF, WIM, XAR and Z.
> - For ZIP and GZIP formats, 7-Zip provides a compression ratio that is 2-10 % better than the ratio provided by PKZip and WinZip
> - Strong AES-256 encryption in 7z and ZIP formats
> - Self-extracting capability for 7z format
> - Integration with Windows Shell
> - Powerful File Manager
> - Powerful command line version
> - Plugin for FAR Manager
> - Localizations for 74 languages

Answer (score 1):

Winzip should also do the job fine

Comment: winzip costs money for the full version

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/). It uses up less RAM. Look [here](http://gomeler.com/2006/07/08/file-compression-review/) for a face-off between WinRAR and 7-zip.